# CldUploadButton don't work with shadn dialog component

Tags: next.js, cloudinary, shadcnui

When i click in CldUploadButton to render the area to upload an image, this area show in browser,but seems to be behind of the dialog from shadcn. No events work, actually everything on the dialog is clickable even if is below in the interface. If this CldUploadButton is render in any other part of the application it  works, but i need to be in my dialog.

I also tried to use the CldUploadWidget and also dont work.

```
"use client"

import React, { useState } from 'react'

//dialog
import {
    Dialog,
    DialogContent,
    DialogDescription,
    DialogHeader,
    DialogTitle,
    DialogTrigger,
    DialogClose
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import { Button } from '../ui/button';
import { Input } from '../ui/input';

import { User } from '@prisma/client'
import AvatarProfile from '../Avatar';
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { FieldValues, SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import axios from 'axios';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { CldUploadButton  } from 'next-cloudinary';
import { TfiExchangeVertical } from "react-icons/tfi";


interface SettingsProps {
    currentUser: User;
}

const SettingsDialog = ({ currentUser }: SettingsProps) => {
    const [loading, setloading] = useState<boolean>(false)
    const router = useRouter()

    const { register, handleSubmit, setValue, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm<FieldValues>({
        defaultValues: {
            name: currentUser?.name,
            image: currentUser?.image
        }
    })
    // image upload
    const image = watch("image")
    const handleUpload = (result: any) => {
        // valor vindo do cloudinary
        setValue("image", result?.info?.secure_url, {
            shouldValidate: true
        })
    }

    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = (data) => {
        setloading(true)
        axios.post("/api/settings", data)
            .then(() => {
                router.refresh()
            })
            .catch(() => toast.error("Alguma coisa deu errado "))
            .finally(() => setloading(false))
    }


    return (
        <Dialog>
            <DialogTrigger>
                <div className="cursor-pointer hover:opacity-75  hover:text-main transition">
                    <AvatarProfile user={currentUser} />
                </div>
            </DialogTrigger>
            <DialogContent >
                <DialogHeader>
                    <DialogTitle>Configuração de Perfil</DialogTitle>
                    <DialogDescription className="mt-1 text-sm leading-6 text-gray-600">Edite suas informações!</DialogDescription>
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                        <div className="space-y-12">
                            <div className="border-b border-gray-900/10 pb-12">
                                <div className="mt-5 flex flex-col gap-y-8">
                                    <div>
                                        <label
                                            htmlFor="photo"
                                            className="block text-sm font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900"
                                        >
                                            Photo
                                        </label>
                                        <div className="mt-2 flex flex-col items-center gap-x-3  z-[100] relative">
                                            <Image
                                                width="100"
                                                height="100"
                                                className="rounded-full"
                                                src={image || currentUser?.image}
                                                alt="Avatar"
                                            />
                                            <DialogClose>





                                                <CldUploadButton
                                                    options={{ maxFiles: 1 }}
                                                    onUpload={handleUpload}
                                                    uploadPreset='My-preset'
                                                >
                                                    <Button
                                                        className='flex gap-1 items-center bg-transparent text-gray-900 shadow-none hover:text-main hover:bg-transparent transition ease-in-out text-sm font-medium leading-6'
                                                        disabled={loading}
                                                        type="button"
                                                    >
                                                        Change
                                                        <TfiExchangeVertical size={20} />
                                                    </Button>
                                                </CldUploadButton>







                                            </DialogClose>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label className='text-sm font-medium leading-6'>
                                        Nome
                                        <Input
                                            disabled={loading}
                                            {...register("name")}
                                        />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="mt-6 flex items-center justify-end gap-x-6">
                            <DialogClose>
                                <Button
                                    className='bg-transparent text-gray-900 font-bold shadow-none  hover:text-main hover:bg-transparent transition ease-in-out'
                                    type='button'
                                    disabled={loading}
                                >
                                    Cancel
                                </Button>
                            </DialogClose>
                            <DialogClose>
                                <Button
                                    className='bg-transparent text-white font-bold shadow-none bg-main hover:shadow-md hover:bg-main hover:opacity-80 hover:scale-105 transition-all'
                                    disabled={loading}
                                    type="submit"
                                >
                                    Save
                                </Button>
                            </DialogClose>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </DialogHeader>
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>

    )
}

export default SettingsDialog
```